# What will be the code for this? you have to solve with python

Tags: python, string

**What will be the code for this?**
The input format: Read a word or a phrase written in lowerCamelCase.

The output format: Print out words in lowercase and separate them by underscores.

Sample Input 1: parselTongue

Sample Output 1: parsel_tongue

Comment: Please review [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) -- to highlight one of the key points, we insist that questions here be about a *specific problem* with your *existing implementation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you need:

```
snake_case = ""
variableName = "parselTongue"
for character in variableName:
    if character.isupper():
        snake_case += "_"+character.lower()
    else:
        snake_case += character

print(snake_case)
```

Comment: thanks man. i was stucked in this problem from many days.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_uppercase(string):
x=''
for i in string: 
    if i.isupper(): x+=' %s' %i 
    else: x+=i 
l=x.strip().split()
return '_'.join(l)
```

print(split_uppercase("parselTongue"))